# How can I log the activity of a directory?

Tags: log, gnome-activity-journal

I need to know which files have been copied to or removed from a directory or folder such `/dev` or `/mnt` or any other directory.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why have you included the [gnome-activity-journal] tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `inotifywait` to monitor directories for files that have been accessed, deleted or moved.

Install [inotify-tools](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=inotify-tools&searchon=names)

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install inotify-tools
```

Then run:

```
inotifywait -m -r /mnt
```

The "`-m`" option monitors the directory and "`-r`" is recursive. Unless otherwise specified by "`-e`" option, all events will be displayed as defined in the `inotifywait` manpage. The events can be sent to a log file by using the "`-o`" option:

```
inotifywait -m -r -o /directory/logfile.txt /mnt
```